# How to make that design MenuStrip or toolstrip?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I was wondering how some applications have a menubar/toolstrip on the left and when the button is clicked--instead of a new form opening--options just open up on the empty space on the right like an embedded form.

Any advice, clue, hint Please tell me

Thank you.

Comment: A screenshot of such an application would be much easier to understand than trying to imagine this.

Comment: You know like the one in VS 2010 itself and some payroll programs too and what about those collapsible menus what are those?

Comment: Docking panels? Like [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/), perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to have a dock-able panel same as toolbox in visual studio.
You can achieve this by using tab controls an tweaking with its properties. The following link contains a demo on that. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/toolbars/SimpleDockableForm.aspx